# pandas dataframe integer index to date index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that is indexed by an integer value corresponding to a year (for example, 2016).  I want to convert the index to datetime, with each date corresponding to the end of June of the year indicated by the integer index.  When I do:

```
    dstr = df.index.values[0]
    estr = df.index.values[-1]
    st = '06/30/' + str(dstr)
    e = '06/30/' + str(estr)
    df.index = pandas.date_range(start = st, end = e, freq='A-JUN')
```

This code creates, in addition to the expected data, a separate set of data which appears to have identical indices but the values are all NaN.  When I print the database I only see the non-NaN values, but when I print df[df.isnull()] i see all the data as NaN.  How do I convert properly without these NaN's?

Comment: Can you provide a complete example (maybe with dummy data)?  It's not clear exactly what you mean by 'creates a separate set of data'.  As written, your code should work.

Comment: Also, if you want to filter rows that have a `NaN` value, you need to write it is `df[df.isnull().any(1)]`